# robots.txt and disallow

Tags: robots.txt, mediawiki

Which one is correct?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: index.php
```

or

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php
```

inorder to block all pages like `index.php?day=7` `index.php?day=15` `index.php?day=30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following robots.txt file if you wish to block all robots from accessing your pages.

```
# robots.txt for www.domain.com to block all bots

User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

If you wish to block all all URLs that include a question mark (?) you can use the following format

```
# robots.txt for www.domain.com to block URL with ? mark

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?
```

For more detailed information on how to write robots.txt visit the following link
[How to Create Robots.txt Files](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/)

Answer (score 3):

The second one is better form as it clearly marks the index.php as being the in web root and not in some other subdirectory.

Comment: Isn't the robots.txt used to block directories and not files?

Comment: It can block both